# Who needs to worry about prototype pollution?

Tags: javascript, security

Is [prototype pollution](https://snyk.io/blog/after-three-years-of-silence-a-new-jquery-prototype-pollution-vulnerability-emerges-once-again/) a problem that every Javascript programmer must guard against in their code? I can picture many programmers writing their own object creation and update functions.

I have written a grouping function which creates new (nested) plain objects, with keys taken from existing (nested) plain objects. The keys include user input. Do I need to check for and discard `"__proto__"` keys, or at least sanitize them before they reach that function?

---

Example: Let's say the function takes in:

```
{
    "valueA": {
        "item0": "A0",
        "item1": "A1",
    },
    "valueB": {
        "item0": "B0",
        "item1": "B1",
    },
}
```

It returns:

```
{
    "item0": {
        "valueA": "A0",
        "valueB": "B0",
    },
    "item1": {
        "valueA": "A1",
        "valueB": "B1",
    },
}
```

Comment: I considered posting this in SE Security, but the answer is more relevant to developers than security experts.

Comment: @Paulpro You can make an object with its own enumerable `__proto__`: `{ "__proto__": {"foo": "bar"} }`.

Comment: @leewz Notice that in a web-compat browser environment, that actually creates an empty object with a custom prototype. You could however use `JSON.parse('{ "__proto__": {"foo": "bar"} }')` (or use `Object.defineProperty`, or assign to `Object.create(null)`, …)

Comment: [This paper](https://github.com/HoLyVieR/prototype-pollution-nsec18/raw/master/paper/JavaScript_prototype_pollution_attack_in_NodeJS.pdf) seems to be a more useful introduction, and contains mitigation steps in the end.